# Fooman Email Attachment Extension on Magento attach symmetrics PDF

Tags: php, magento, pdf, magento-1.7, invoice

i am trying to attach a pdf invoice with the fooman Extension to Email Transactions. The problem is that the attached pdf version doesn't look like the pdf that i can print from the backend.

I contacted Fooman and they told me that the extension Symmetrics invoice PDF ist responsible for this. Could anyone please tell me how can i attach the same PDF like the one i can print ? (the one that have been changed from Symmetrics extension). Because Fooman only attach the default invoice.

Does anyone have an idea how i can solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The only thing to do is to tell Foomann to use the Symmetrics Order Model.

Just add this to Fooman EmailAttachments config.xml in between global / models:

```
<sales>
   <rewrite>
       <order_pdf_invoice>Symmetrics_InvoicePdf_Model_Pdf_Invoice</order_pdf_invoice>
   </rewrite>
</sales>
```

Regards
fabstr